# While rotating an image its changing the actual position of the image

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, image-rotation

I tried to rotate the bitmap using Matrix , its working fine if the angle is 90degrees other than 90 degrees the bitmap position is getting changed.

Code Snippet:

```
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Bitmap map= Bitmap.createBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0,resizedBitmap.getWidth(), resizedBitmap.getHeight(),matrix, true);
```

can you guys tell me how to rotate the image without changing position of the image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hii if you are using ImageView I would suggest to set the matrix for ImageView rather than creating a new bitmap everytime something like this

```
              Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
     img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   
     int height =  img.arrow.getHeight();
        int width =  img.arrow.getWidth();
    matrix.postRotate((float) angle, width/2,height/2);
     img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: i am not using an imageview in this, i created custom view which extends View object, so i have to use bitmap only here.

Comment: Y can u try this code  matrix.postRotate((float) angle, this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2); I am not sure whether it works correctly or not,jus a guess it worked well for ImageView

Answer (score 0):

This one the only one worked for me

```
private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int rotationAngleDegree){

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int newW=w, newH=h;
        if (rotationAngleDegree==90 || rotationAngleDegree==270){
            newW = h;
            newH = w;
        }
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newW,newH, bitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rotatedBitmap);

        Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,newW, newH);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        float px = rect.exactCenterX();
        float py = rect.exactCenterY();
        matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth()/2, -bitmap.getHeight()/2);
        matrix.postRotate(rotationAngleDegree);
        matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG ));
        matrix.reset();

        return rotatedBitmap;
    }
```